# Can't display picture in CDetailView Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I am learning PHP Yii 1.1
I'm trying to upload picture while creating a new user and display the picture in the view (in `CDetailView`).

In uploading picture process, I could save the name of the pic in the database and save the picture in a folder called `banner` which is included in `protected` folder.

I want now to display the pic in the view, I tried all the solutions I've found, but still doesn't work with me.

```
<h1>View User #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>

<?php 
//die(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/protected/banner/' . $model->picture);
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
      'data'=>$model,
      'attributes'=>array(
          'id',
          'username',
          'address',
          'email',
           array(
             'name'=>'picture',
             'type'=>'raw',
             'value'=>CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/protected/banner/' . $model->picture),
           )
      ),
)); ?>
```

I checked the image URL by executing this command, and it gave me the right path of the saved image:

```
die(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/protected/banner/' . $model->picture);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to `protected` directory is disallowed to protect all internal files of your applications. You need to create this directory outside of `protected` directory if you want to link to files inside of it:

```
   array(
     'name'=>'picture',
     'type'=>'raw',
     'value'=>CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/banner/' . $model->picture),
   )
```

Comment: Ooooh I wasted hours without realizing this issue! Thank you soooo much :)